# Take element of a Set collection depending on the value of another element

Tags: java, collections, set

I had to populate the fields of a `Service` object using a `Set` (HashSet) with any configuration parameters -> `ConfigurationMap` (Class with 2 attributes: key and value).
The problem is that the attribute `quantity` of `Service` object can be set from two distinct parameters ("service_quantity" or "publications_amount") based on the value of another parameter("type").

I've gotten it to work with the code below, but I think it's pretty messy and inefficient.
Is there any way to make it more readable considering that the methods signatures are invariable?

```
@Override
protected void populateServiceConfigurationData(Service theService, Set<ConfigurationMap> configurationParams) {
    boolean publishService = false;
    for (ConfigurationMap configParam : configurationParams) {
        String paramValue = configParam.getValue();
        String paramKey = configParam.getKey();
        setFieldValue(theService, paramKey, paramValue);
        if("type".equals(paramKey) && paramValue.equals("20")) {
            publishService = true;
        }
    }

    if(publishService) {
        for (ConfigurationMap configParam : configurationParams) {
            String paramKey = configParam.getKey();
            if(paramKey.equals("publications_amount")) {
                String paramValue = configParam.getValue();
                setFieldValue(theService, paramKey, paramValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void setFieldValue(Service service, String paramKey, String paramValue) {
    if ("type".equals(paramKey)) {
        service.setType(Integer.valueOf(paramValue));
    }
    if ("service_quantity".equals(paramKey) || "publications_amount".equals(paramKey)) {
        service.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(paramValue));
    }
    if ("gateway_id".equals(paramKey)) {
        service.setGatewayId(paramValue);
    }
    if ("comissions".equals(paramKey)) {
        service.setCommissions(paramValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Instead of `Set<ConfigurationMap>`, why don't you turn ConfigurationMap itself into a Map such as a HashMap?

Comment: The method signature can't be changed